# Unexpected error (validator) during bootstrapping

Tags: node, docker, bootstrapping

I recently brought up a new node via docker and saw it got stuck during bootstrapping.

```
$ ./mainnet.sh client bootstrapped

Current head: BMeUZ1D6FWZv (timestamp: 2019-06-20T16:54:00-00:00, validation: 2019-06-21T07:49:34-00:00)
```

When I check the node logs I see over and over again:

```
Jun 21 07:50:37 - validator.peer_431: Worker crashed [NetXdQprcVkpa:idqWQvWjXsHA]:
Jun 21 07:50:37 - validator.peer_431: "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/state.ml:1214:36"
Jun 21 07:50:37 - validator.peer_431: "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/state.ml:1214:36"
Jun 21 07:50:37 - validator.peer_431: "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/state.ml:1214:36"
Jun 21 07:50:37 - validator.peer_431: "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/state.ml:1214:36"
Jun 21 07:50:37 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Jun 21 07:50:37 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error, dumping error stack:
Jun 21 07:50:37 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/state.ml:1214:36"
Jun 21 07:50:37 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/state.ml:1214:36"
Jun 21 07:50:37 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/state.ml:1214:36"
Jun 21 07:50:37 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   "Assert_failure src/lib_shell/state.ml:1214:36"
Jun 21 07:50:37 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:
```

That leads to this code: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_shell/state.ml#L1207-1219

But I'm OCaml illiterate. I'm not sure what the problem is.

CPU, memory and other stats look fine.

Any ideas on what's going wrong or how to debug this?

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you open an issue on https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/ ?

And a few details such as :

- is your script up to date ?
- did you bootstrapped your node from nothing ? Or used a storage snashpot ?
- are you running your node in Full or Rolling (or don't know) mode ?